# Why can´t I implement Primary key in my SQL Table?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I try to save Data in my esp32. In my table there should be a primary key so that I can´t save something twice with the same id. But I get an error

The Error Code:

```
SQL error: disk I/O error
```

That´s the whole Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "esp_err.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_spiffs.h"
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

static const char *TAG = "sqlite3_spiffs";

const char* data = "Callback function called";
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   int i;
   printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
   for (i = 0; i<argc; i++){
       printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

int db_open(const char *filename, sqlite3 **db) {
   int rc = sqlite3_open(filename, db);
   if (rc) {
       printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
       return rc;
   } else {
       printf("Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   return rc;
}

char *zErrMsg = 0;
int db_exec(sqlite3 *db, const char *sql) {
   printf("%s\n", sql);
   int64_t start = esp_timer_get_time();
   int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
       printf("Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   printf("Time taken: %lld\n", esp_timer_get_time()-start);
   return rc;
}

void setup()
{
    sqlite3 *db1;

    int rc;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Initializing SPIFFS");
    
    esp_vfs_spiffs_conf_t conf = {
      .base_path = "/spiffs",
      //.partition_label = "storage",
      .partition_label = NULL,
      .max_files = 5,
      .format_if_mount_failed = true
    };
    
    // Use settings defined above to initialize and mount SPIFFS filesystem.
    // Note: esp_vfs_spiffs_register is an all-in-one convenience function.
    esp_err_t ret = esp_vfs_spiffs_register(&conf);

    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        if (ret == ESP_FAIL) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount or format filesystem");
        } else if (ret == ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to find SPIFFS partition");
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize SPIFFS (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        }
        return;
    }
    
    size_t total = 0, used = 0;
    ret = esp_spiffs_info(NULL, &total, &used);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get SPIFFS partition information (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
    } else {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Partition size: total: %d, used: %d", total, used);
    }

    // remove existing file
    unlink("/spiffs/test1.db");
    unlink("/spiffs/test2.db");

    sqlite3_initialize();

    if (db_open("/spiffs/test1.db", &db1))
        return;
    

    rc = db_exec(db1, "CREATE TABLE entries(id STRING PRIMARY KEY, value ,section)");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);
        return;
    }

    
    rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO entries VALUES ('ROOMNAME', 'HH180L23G', 'general');");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);
        return;
    }

    rc = db_exec(db1, "SELECT * FROM entries");
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db1);
        return;
    }


    sqlite3_close(db1);
 

    // All done, unmount partition and disable SPIFFS
    esp_vfs_spiffs_unregister(NULL);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SPIFFS unmounted");

    //while(1);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I have ideas like that it has something to do with spiffs or with the mounting ..
I tried both partition.labels .. it´s the same error ..
I can´t figure out why it doesn´t let me take a primary key .. the same thing as I can´t implement unique Text or something I get the same error..

Did someone have experienced it before ?
It would be such a huge support

Log Monitor:

```
Opened database successfully
CREATE TABLE entries(id STRING PRIMARY KEY, value ,section)
SQL error: disk I/O error
Time taken: 179044
```

Comment: As indicated by the error message, SQL is not the problem here. The database file cannot be opened. Have you actually created a [SPIFFS partition](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html), [mounted it](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html#functions), etc? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which includes the file system management.

Comment: @Tarmo the database is opened. I will show you the whole Log which comes out.

Comment: The log shows that you got a disk error creating the table, which indicates that the disk,, not the SQL, is the problem here, exactly as @Tarmo has already told you.

Comment: @user207421 what should I do exactly.. can you give me some hints..

Comment: The root cause is that sqlite cannot write to the file system. Maybe it's full. Wipe the partition using idf.py, try again. Allocate at least a few hundred KiB to the file system partition. As for the SQL, I suggest a different approach. Before writing a bunch of code to programmatically manipulate a database, install sqlite3 on your PC and test the SQL syntax manually. Much easier, much faster. There's a typo in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, it's missing the semicolon.

Comment: But if I let the PRIMARY KEY out It creates my table and Insert the value.. @Tarmo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known problem: https://github.com/siara-cc/esp32_arduino_sqlite3_lib/issues/18

Somebody has posted a workaround/fix, which doesn't look very promising to me - they explicitly specify the label of the SPIFFS partition when mounting it. Try it, see if it works.
https://github.com/siara-cc/esp32-idf-sqlite3/issues/13

Comment: I tried this already.. it doesn´t work

Comment: Then you have to try the other workarounds in the thread above, create a database then add the index; use other file systems, etc.

Comment: If I change the partition label to "storage" .. I get the error that the spiffs partition is not found

Comment: Well, you have to supply the correct label value, not a random one from the Internet. The one that your partition table specifies. How about posting your partition table, to begin with.

Comment: How can I show the partition table of my chip ?

Comment: In Arduino I use the Default Partition scheme 4Mb with spiffs (1.2MB App / 1.5MB Spiffs)

Comment: File partitions.csv in project root?

Comment: I only have one File .. and I uploaded it only from Arduino into my ESP32

Comment: According to the [default partitions](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/partitions/default.csv) in Arduino your partition label is "spiffs"

Comment: Yes that´s right I told you before.

Comment: In `esp_vfs_spiffs_conf_t ` you should have `.partition_label = "spiffs"`

Comment: I got again an error : SQL error : Disk I/O error

Comment: I have changed it to "spiffs"

Comment: OK, then the workaround was not working. Try another file system, I suspect SPIFFS may lack some feature which sqlite requires.

Comment: which File System can I put on .. here ?

Comment: FAT, LittleFS. Also consider using something simpler than an SQL DB for storing your data, such as NVS.